# How do I make this axios call inside my own API route?

Tags: express, axios

This is my first time trying to make an API call to a third party while inside my own API route. The following code does not work because I get the error "Cannot use import statement outside a module." This code is called by a thunk at the front end.

If I can't import axios, what's an alternative?

EDIT: I got rid of the error by doing 'const axios = require('axios') but now the results I'm getting is undefined.

EDIT2: Resolved. Through use of the following:

```html
router.get("/:zip", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let data = [];
    await axios
      .get(`https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.SECRET_KEY_YELP}`,
        },
        params: {
          location: req.params.zip,
          //   categories: "coffee",
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        data = response.data;
      });
    res.send(data);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

ORIGINAL CODE WITH ISSUE:

```html
const router = require("express").Router();
module.exports = router;
import axios from "axios";
router.get("/:zip", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    //const restaurants = await Test.findAll({})
    const result = await axios.get(
      `https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?location=${req.params.zip}`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.SECRET_KEY_YELP}`,
        },
        params: {
          categories: "coffee",
        },
      }
    ).data;
    res.send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried putting thóe in a module?

Answer (score 0):

Posted above. It needed a .then snippet.

```html
  let data = [];
    await axios
      .get(`https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.SECRET_KEY_YELP}`,
        },
        params: {
          location: req.params.zip,
          //   categories: "coffee",
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        data = response.data;
      });
    res.send(data);
```